# Angular4 HttpClient stringify an object containing an other object

Tags: json, angular, httpclient

I try to make a post request to an API of an object containing another object in his structure but I've got an error. The error is not clear but after debugging I came to the conclusion that the json in the request is invalid.

Here are my structures, I truncated getter and setter to keep the code minimal :

```js
export class Spot {
    protected _id: number;
    protected _name: string;
    protected _address: string;
    protected _city: City;
}

export class City {
    protected _id: number;
    protected _name: string;
}
```

and here is my service :

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment.prod';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Spot } from './../../models/spot';

const spotUrl = environment.BASE_API_URL + 'blasti/spots';

@Injectable()
export class AdminSpotService {

  private headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'});

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllSpots(): Observable<Spot[]> {
    return this._http.get<Spot[]>(spotUrl);
  }

  createSpot(spot: Spot): Observable<Spot> {
    console.log(spot);
    return this._http.post<Spot>(spotUrl, spot, { headers: this.headers });
  }
}
```

The console.log(spot) gives : 
`Spot {_name: "name", _address: "fefe", _city: "[object Object]"}
address
:
(...)
city
:
(...)
id
:
(...)
name
:
(...)
_address
:
"fefe"
_city
:
"[object Object]"
_name
:
"name"`

and the API receives `{_name: "name", _address: "fefe", _city: "[object Object]"}` which is invalid because of _city that is not stringifyed by the post method.

PS: I had the same result with the HttpModule + JSON.stringify(spot). The HttpClientModule is available for Angular 4.3 and up and it normally stringify objects without specifying the JSON.stringify().

I hope that some experts of angular had a solution.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It IS stringified before the `console.log`, you can see it obviously is `_city: "[object Object]"` there

Comment: _city has to be stringified too, i need `_city:{"_name": "Paris", "_country": "France"}` instead of Object.

Comment: What I meant was the object is in bad form BEFORE getting passed into this createPost function.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the problem come when getting the informations from the from, here is my code :

```js
<form [formGroup]="spotForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name">
  <input type="text" formControlName="address">
  <select formControlName="city">
    <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city">{{city.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

and my component :

```js
export class CreateSpotComponent {
  spotForm: FormGroup;
  cities: City[] = [new City({
    _name: 'Paris'
  })];

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder, private _spotService: AdminSpotService) {
    this.createForm();
   }

   createForm() {
    this.spotForm = this._formBuilder.group({
       name: '',
       address: '',
       city: ''
     });
   }

   onSubmit() {
     const spotModel = this.spotForm.value;
     const saveSpot: Spot = new Spot({
      name: spotModel.name,
      city: spotModel.city
     });
     this._spotService.createSpot(saveSpot);
   }
}
```

So how to get the right city object value from the form instead of having [object Object] ?

Thank you

Comment: I found the solution, the mistake was coming from the Form, i had to use [ngValue]="city" instead of [value]="city"